# Validate woocommerce cart depending on shop archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to validate the woocommerce cart with`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` based on the unique shop archive page the user is currently on? I am adding to the cart via ajax.

e.g.

- IF user is on Page *strongshop* AND max item count is *20*...apply rule.
- IF user is on Page *smallshop* AND max item count is *10*....apply rule.

**This code snippet below works and applies the validation based on `$item_count >= 20`:**

```
// Prevent Redirect after cart error
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', '__return_false'); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'restrict_only_one_item_in_cart' );

 function restrict_only_one_item_in_cart($cart_item_data) {

   global $woocommerce;
   $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

   if($item_count >= 20){
      return false;
   }
   return $cart_item_data;
}
```

When I update the IF condition and add in the `is_page()` constraint in order to apply the rule to certain pages. `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` does not trigger at all.

**Updated IF condition below with `is_page()`:**

```
   if((is_page('strongshop') || is_page('strongshopmobile')) && $item_count >= 20){
      return false;
```

Items are being added to the cart via AJAX, so I'm stumped as to why this isn't triggering...any suggestions?

Comment: If you were adding to the cart via AJAX, yes. By default, WooCommerce will navigate to a new page, and therefore, you will not know what page the user was on. Alternatively, you could pass a an extra parameter in the Add To Cart call that would store the current url. This way you could check the url in your filter logic.

Comment: Yes, I am adding to the cart via AJAX, however the above does not apply the validation...Where can I pass in an extra parameter in the Add To Cart call?

Comment: Have you confirmed your is_page() calls are working?

Comment: the above `is_page()` calls are tested and working in other functions...however they don't trigger for the above snippet...if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_restrict_only_one_item_in_cart', 'restrict_only_one_item_in_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_restrict_only_one_item_in_cart', 'restrict_only_one_item_in_cart' );


function restrict_only_one_item_in_cart() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben but it doesn't seem to work...behaviour is same as before, the rule isn't applied.